# How to update a single array from two different components opened in two different tabs in Angular9?

Tags: html, angular, service, angular-services, angular9

I'm building an e-commerce site which I'm implementing an add to cart component which enable users to add an item to a cart and view the items in the cart,I'm using an array to keep track of the added items to cart, Items can be added by two components, from the main page and the item details page, the item details page opens in a new tab when clicked, my issue is after the item details page opens in a new tab it updates its own local cart array, which creates two arrays rather than updating one concurrently.

This is the function in which i have included in both the Main Page and Item details page Components,

```
addToCart(item_id){
this.dataTransmit.changeId(item_id);
}
```

this is the addToCart Function i have implemented in a different component,

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.dataTransmit.currentItemId.subscribe(itemID => {
  this.addToCart(itemID);
});
}

addToCart(itemID){
let itemIdStr: string;
itemIdStr = itemID.toString();
this.cartItemList.push(itemID);
for (let i of this.cartItemList){
  console.log(i);
}
}
```

And this is my service file,

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
 @Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
 })

 export class DataTransmitService {
 private itemId = new BehaviorSubject('');
 currentItemId = this.itemId.asObservable();

 changeId(itemID: any) {
  this.itemId.next(itemID);
  }
  }
```

How do I solve this issue and keep an a single array storing the products selected across all tabs?

Comment: Sounds like you would want to use localStorage to store your items. You could create observable version of it using storage event which is triggered on other browser tabs telling them to update if something changed in it from diffrent tab.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it worked on my chrome browser but didn't work when I went through firefox, I sent it to a friend and he had the problem with both the browsers, it seems like the browser needs authorization? is there a way to solve it?

Comment: local storage works only on the same browser if you want to keep synch between diffrent browsers you need to create backend for keeping track of array state

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62048849/how-to-get-angular-project-with-localstorage-to-work-in-every-browser/62048920#62048920