# How to get angular project with localStorage to work in every browser?

Tags: angular, typescript, browser, local-storage, angular9

I'm working on a e-com site which has a cart list component, I implemented it using localStorage as follows,

```
 export class CheckOutHomePageComponent implements OnInit {

currentArr:string;
myCart:string[] = [];
prices:any;
constructor(
private dataTransmit: DataTransmitService,
private itemsService: ItemsService,
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
this.dataTransmit.currentItemId.subscribe(itemID => {
  this.myCart = [];
  this.myCart = this.addToCart(itemID);
  for(let i of this.myCart){
    console.log("myCart : "+i);
  }
});
}

addToCart(itemID){
let isAdded = false;
let itemIdStr: string;
let currentArrA:string[] = [];
this.currentArr = localStorage.getItem('currentArray');
itemIdStr = itemID.toString();
currentArrA = this.currentArr.split(",");
for(let i of currentArrA){
  if(i===itemIdStr){
    isAdded = true
  }
}
if(!isAdded){
  localStorage.setItem("currentArray", this.currentArr+","+itemIdStr);
}
this.currentArr = localStorage.getItem('currentArray');
// console.log(this.currentArr);
currentArrA = this.currentArr.split(",");
return currentArrA;
}

clearList(){
localStorage.setItem("currentArray","");
console.log("cleared..."+localStorage.getItem('currentArray'));
this.myCart = [];
}
}
```

This works fine on my chrome browser and the console displays the log of myCart array, I sent it to my friend and it doesn't work for him in both browsers, I tried it with firefox and it didn't work for me as well, I'm guessing the function localStorage needs some sort of authorization from the browser? how do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

localStorage can handle only string key/value pairs.

```
localStorage.setItem('currentArray', JSON.stringify(this.currentArr));
// and:
const o = localStorage.getItem('currentArray');
if (o) {
   this.currentArr = JSON.parse(o);
}
```

There is no need for  extra authentication.

See: [can i use localStorage](https://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage).

And: [MDN localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)

Comment: kinda confused on what you're getting at, I am already passing string key/value pairs.

Comment: I'm passing the entire myCart as a list separated by commas and then splitting it by the comma to add it into a new array. this code works fine when I open the localhost through chrome on my pc btw

Comment: and my friends on chrome 81, which is listed as compatible